# OptaPlanner solution for NQueens problem with more queens on chess board than necessary

Tags: spring, spring-boot, optaplanner, n-queens

I want to implement OptaPlanner in my SpringBoot/Java app for solving NQueen problem. Implementation that I already have is from OptaPlanner documentation and it works perfectly for exact number of queens necessary for chess board, it is not copied from documentation, I used documentation instruction to make my own solution.

Now I want to make a solution so that when I pass more queens than necessary, excess queen/queens will not be assigned position.

My solution is available [here](https://github.com/jova5/opta-planner-nqueens) on github. It is still work in progress because I could not get result similar to result mentioned bellow.

This is code for managing queens on chess board filed (functionality for excess and non excess queens),

```
public class ChessTableConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {
    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[]{oneQueenInTheField(constraintFactory), rowConflict(constraintFactory),
                columnConflict(constraintFactory), diagonalConflict(constraintFactory),
                onePositionNotNullOtherNull(constraintFactory), positionNotNull(constraintFactory)};
    }

    Constraint oneQueenInTheField(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                    .join(Queen.class, Joiners.equal(Queen::getRowIndex),
                                          Joiners.equal(Queen::getColumnIndex), Joiners.lessThan(Queen::getId))
                                    .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                    .asConstraint("One queen at most in the field");
        }
    
        Constraint rowConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                    .join(Queen.class, Joiners.equal(Queen::getRowIndex), Joiners.lessThan(Queen::getId))
                                    .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                    .asConstraint("Queens on same row");
        }
    
    
        Constraint columnConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                    .join(Queen.class, Joiners.equal(Queen::getColumnIndex), Joiners.lessThan(Queen::getId))
                                    .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                    .asConstraint("Queens on same column");
        }
    
    
        Constraint diagonalConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                    .join(Queen.class, Joiners.lessThan(Queen::getId))
                                    .filter((queen1, queen2) -> queen1.getRowIndex() != null &&
                                                                queen1.getColumnIndex() != null &&
                                                                queen2.getRowIndex() != null &&
                                                                queen2.getColumnIndex() != null)
                                    .filter((queen1, queen2) -> Math.abs(queen1.getRowIndex() - queen2.getRowIndex()) ==
                                                                Math.abs(queen1.getColumnIndex() - queen2.getColumnIndex()))
                                    .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                    .asConstraint("Queens on same diagonal");
        }
    
        Constraint positionNotNull(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                    .filter(queen -> queen.getRowIndex() == null && queen.getColumnIndex() == null)
                                    .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                    .asConstraint("Position must not be null");
        }
    
        Constraint onePositionNotNullOtherNull(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class).filter(queen -> {
                if (queen.getColumnIndex() == null && queen.getRowIndex() == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                return queen.getRowIndex() == null || queen.getColumnIndex() == null;
            }).penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD).asConstraint("Only one position is null");
        }
    }
```

Example result for chess board size 4x4, number of queens 5:

```
{
   "queenList":[
      {
         "id":0,
         "columnIndex":null,
         "rowIndex":null
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "columnIndex":2,
         "rowIndex":0
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "columnIndex":0,
         "rowIndex":1
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "columnIndex":3,
         "rowIndex":2
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "columnIndex":1,
         "rowIndex":3
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, one queen is not assigned to position.

My environment:
Laptop: Dell Vostro 5625
OS: Win11
Processor: Ryzen 7 5xxx
Ram: 32GB

I thank everyone for their time.

Edit 1, solution:

```
public class ChessTableConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {
    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[]{oneQueenInTheField(constraintFactory), rowConflict(constraintFactory),
                columnConflict(constraintFactory), diagonalConflict(constraintFactory),
                rewardAssignedQueens(constraintFactory), anyPositionAssignedWithNull(constraintFactory)};
    }

    Constraint oneQueenInTheField(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                .join(Queen.class, Joiners.equal(Queen::getRowIndex),
                                      Joiners.equal(Queen::getColumnIndex), Joiners.lessThan(Queen::getId))
                                .filter((queen1, queen2) -> queen1.getRowIndex() != null &&
                                                            queen1.getColumnIndex() != null &&
                                                            queen2.getRowIndex() != null &&
                                                            queen2.getColumnIndex() != null)
                                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                .asConstraint("One queen at most in the field");
    }

    Constraint rowConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                .join(Queen.class, Joiners.equal(Queen::getRowIndex), Joiners.lessThan(Queen::getId))
                                .filter((queen, queen2) -> queen.getRowIndex() != null && queen2.getRowIndex() != null)
                                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                .asConstraint("Queens on same row");
    }

    Constraint columnConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                .join(Queen.class, Joiners.equal(Queen::getColumnIndex), Joiners.lessThan(Queen::getId))
                                .filter((queen, queen2) -> queen.getColumnIndex() != null &&
                                                           queen2.getColumnIndex() != null)
                                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                .asConstraint("Queens on same column");
    }

    Constraint diagonalConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                .join(Queen.class, Joiners.lessThan(Queen::getId))
                                .filter((queen1, queen2) -> queen1.getRowIndex() != null &&
                                                            queen1.getColumnIndex() != null &&
                                                            queen2.getRowIndex() != null &&
                                                            queen2.getColumnIndex() != null)
                                .filter((queen1, queen2) -> Math.abs(queen1.getRowIndex() - queen2.getRowIndex()) ==
                                                            Math.abs(queen1.getColumnIndex() - queen2.getColumnIndex()))
                                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                .asConstraint("Queens on same diagonal");
    }

    Constraint rewardAssignedQueens(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                .filter((queen1) -> queen1.getRowIndex() != null && queen1.getColumnIndex() != null)
                                .reward(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM)
                                .asConstraint("Reward Assigned Queens");
    }

    Constraint anyPositionAssignedWithNull(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Queen.class)
                                .filter(queen -> queen.getRowIndex() == null || queen.getColumnIndex() == null)
                                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                .asConstraint("Any Position Assigned With Null");
    }
}
```

Now I get this result:

```
{
   "queenList": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "rowIndex": 1,
            "columnIndex": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "rowIndex": 3,
            "columnIndex": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "rowIndex": 0,
            "columnIndex": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "rowIndex": 2,
            "columnIndex": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "rowIndex": null,
            "columnIndex": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [over-constrained planning](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#overconstrainedPlanning).
You need to tell the solver that it is OK not to assign some entities.